# How to get client ip address in socket.io 2.0.3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am currently using socket.io v2.0.3 in node.js server and can't find a way to get client's IP address.

There are numerous of tips & tricks all around stackoverflow but they are outdated and not working anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the **socket.handshake**

```
{
  headers: /* the headers sent as part of the handshake */,
  time: /* the date of creation (as string) */,
  address: /* the ip of the client */,
  xdomain: /* whether the connection is cross-domain */,
  secure: /* whether the connection is secure */,
  issued: /* the date of creation (as unix timestamp) */,
  url: /* the request URL string */,
  query: /* the query object */
}
```

See [this](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-client) link

**Edit:** turns it it might have changed to **socket.request.connection.remoteAddress**, see [this](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/issues/102) link.

**Edit2** : Issue could be related to Client and Server version unaligned.

Comment: Here's what I see:

{
 "headers":{
  "user-agent":"websocket-sharp/1.0",
  "upgrade":"websocket",
  "connection":"Upgrade",
  "host":"11.111.11.11:3000",
  "sec-websocket-key":"WOY2i4lbneGJp/8L+dPHSQ==",
  "sec-websocket-version":"13"
    },
 "time":"Mon Aug 28 2017 14:02:43 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
 "xdomain":false,
 "secure":false,
 "issued":1503943363593,
 "url":"/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket",
 "query":{
 "EIO":"4",
 "transport":"websocket"
 }
}

Comment: Feels like they changed things again. Isn't socket.handshake.headers.host  your client ip?

Comment: No, that's a server's IP.

Comment: Then try socket.request.connection.remoteAddress

Comment: That's `undefined` also.

Comment: Maybe try socket.conn.remoteAddress

Comment: I can see that `socket.conn` has a property `remoteAddress`, but it is undefined too.

Comment: Are you using an older client than 2.0.3 ? Feels like your client & server versions are unaligned

Comment: Didn't even think client version can make difference here... I'm actually using Unity and Socket.io package, trying to look into that, but... Not sure if I can do that.

Comment: Just downgraded socket.io to the latest v1 release and suddenly `socket.handshake.address` is defined. Could you please mention the incompatibility problems in your answer?

Comment: @Darker & Eric : check my answer for the reason why and the way to do it correctly until it gets fixed.

Comment: @Darker ADDED IT

Comment: My socket.io server version is v2.0.3, while client is still running on a lower version that 2.0. This causes incompatibility and I found no other solution than downgrading server to v1.7.4 (latest non-v2 release) as I can't modify the client. 
When server and client are compatible, these methods mentioned above work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Currently theres an open issue : [Remote address (IP) is always undefined #2982](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2982)

I'm sure it will get fixed soon, until then there is no reason to downgrade if you really need to obtain the clients IP there is a possible solution.

**proof of concept:**

```
const socketServer = require('socket.io')(3000)
socketServer.on('connection',function(client){
 console.log( client.request.connection._peername.address );
})
const socketCli = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000')
```

**output:**

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Both `socket.handshake.address` and `socket.request.connection._peername.address` seem to work fine but when you use `transports: ['websocket']` in the client then `socket.hanshake.address` and `socket.request.connection._peername` are `undefined`. Hope it will be fixed soon

Comment: Seems like `client.request.connection._peername` does not exist in my scenario. So far only downgrading server to 1.7.4 worked.

Answer (score 2):

In socket.io 2.0: you can use:

`socket.conn.transport.socket._socket.remoteAddress`

works with `transports: ['websocket']`

Answer (score 0):

Successfully getting IP values using `transports: ['websocket']` on the socket connection on all three keys below, version `2.3.0`.

```
socket.request.connection.remoteAddress ::ffff:127.0.0.1
socket.conn.remoteAddress ::ffff:127.0.0.1
socket.conn.transport.socket._socket.remoteAddress ::ffff:127.0.0.1
```